# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect blank DVD+R

Tags: 14.04, dvd

I first checked my system to ensure it accepts/reads/writes DVD+Rs:
I executed `sudo apt-get install libcdio-utils`, and then `sudo cd-drive`.
The output confirmed DVD+R and DVD+RW capability.

Next, I put a blank DVD+R into the drive.

Ubuntu does not detect the disk at all. No reaction on the screen, no messages. Trying to use k3b, Brasero, or Startup Disk Creator renders no result - all prompt me to insert a DVD or CD.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the other answers given...  (I was just burned on this one)

A DVD burner can give up (failed drive motor) without giving any other indication of error.   It was fine a day ago, the tray still does open-close, the system still detects the device... and if you don't hear it spin up there can still be a mechanical problem underneath.

Just to be sure, check that you can still read a non-blank CD.  Listen for the spin-up.

If that's all good then try this:

```
sudo dbus-launch brasero
```

Good luck.